# Quand faut-il mettre un pluriel après un mot indiquant l'absence d'un élément ? — When to use plural after words that hint at a missing entity?

Tags: expressions, grammaire, pluriel

Quelle règle s'applique après un mot comme *sans*, *aucun*, ou une expression comme *pas un seul*, *il n'y a pas*, concernant le nombre du mot suivant ?

Doit-on dire :

- *une dictée sans faute*
- *une dictée sans fautes*
- *Aucune faute ne peut être trouvée dans cette dictée*
- *Aucune fautes ne peuvent être trouvées dans cette dictée*
- *Il n'y a pas de fromage*
- *Il n'y a pas de fromages*
- *Pas un seul athlète n'a franchi cette barre*
- *Pas un seul athlètes n'a franchi cette barre*

Quelle règle permet de déterminer si le singulier ou le pluriel s'applique ?

---

Which rule applies to words that follow *sans*, *aucun*, or phrases like *pas un seul*, *il n'y a pas*? How to know which of singular or plural is acceptable?

Comment: Question (et réponses) fusionnées avec [ce doublon](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/809/dans-quels-cas-doit-on-utiliser-le-pluriel-apres-sans-closed).

Comment: Voir également les réponses à [ce doublon](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1130/pluralization-for-a-count-of-zero-items).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. Pour ce qui est de *sans*, c'est le sens de la phrase qui sert de règle.

   On utilisera un pluriel si ce qui fait défaut (donc l'objet de *sans*), est considéré au pluriel.

   Ainsi :

   > Il fait de la moto sans gants *(on en porte deux en moto)*

   Mais :

   > Il fait de l'escrime sans gant *(on pratique l'escrime avec un seul gant)*

   Dans certains cas, les deux sont acceptables, simplement car on peut considérer ce qui fait défaut des deux façons :

   > Un parcours sans faute *(aucune faute)*
   >
   > Un parcours sans fautes *(il n'y a pas de fautes)*

   Se poser la question de cette façon suffit.

   Et attention !

   > C'est un crédit sans intérêts *(il est gratuit, il n'y a pas d'intérêts à payer)*

   Mais :

   > C'est un crédit sans intérêt *(il n'est pas intéressant. Trop cher, par exemple)*

   J'ai trouvé [une page intéressante](http://www.aidenet.eu/h_sans.htm) qui creuse ce sujet sans trop en faire. Elle comporte par contre et malheureusement de petites erreurs :

   > Une valise sans poignées (*est indiqué comme une faute. Ce n'en est pas une au sens strict du terme. Ce n'est simplement pas très logique*).

   D'ailleurs on dit bien :

   > Une malle sans poignées (*car on considère qu'elle en a normalement plusieurs*)

   Le sens prévaut. Définitivement.
2. Concernant *il n'y a pas*, c'est encore le sens de la phrase qui prévaut :

   > Il n'y a pas de fromage *(au menu)*
   >
   > Mais enfin… il n'y a pas de fromages ! *(dans la vitrine de cette fromagerie)*

   Attention, là encore, si en parlant d'un crédit on vous dit qu'*il n'y a pas d'intérêts*… C'est le même cas que celui vu plus haut : *sans intérêts / sans intérêt*.
3. Pour ce qui est d'*aucun* ou *aucune*, par contre, c'est encore plus simple : ils sont toujours suivis d'un singulier puisqu'*aucun* signifie *pas un seul* :

   > Il n'y a aucun problème.
4. Et de même pour *pas un seul*, puisque précisément on parle *d'un seul* :

   > Pas une seule faute ! Bravo !

Comment: Une faute qui me hérisse particulièrement : « Il n'a fait aucunes fautes »... Brrr !

Comment: Celui qui dit ça en fait une belle, ou plutôt une affreuse, c'est vrai :)

Comment: Peut-on dire "une malle sans poignée" dans le sens de "sans une seule"? (Quand on en attend plusieurs?)

Comment: @Andrew Vit J'aurais plutôt tendance à écrire "une malle sans poignées" du fait que j'en attends plusieurs alors qu'elle n'en a pas une seule. Car si elle en avait ne serait-ce qu'une seule, on dirait plutôt "une malle avec une seule poignée" pour souligner que fait qu'elle n'en a qu'une là où plusieurs sont attendues.

Comment: `Pour ce qui est d'aucun ou aucune, par contre, c'est encore plus simple . . .` un puriste remplacerait `par contre`, par `en revanche`

Comment: Comme pour le reste, "aucun" ou "aucune" peuvent être au pluriel quand ils qualifient un mot qui ne s'emploie qu'au pluriel. Exemple: "Aucunes arrhes ne sont demandées pour passer commande", "aucuns frais ne doivent être engagés avant la validation du projet", etc.

Answer (score 10):

« Pas un seul » précède toujours un singulier.
Le nom suivant « aucun » prend un pluriel si « aucun » est au pluriel.
Dans l’usage, « il n’y a pas de » et « sans » peuvent être suivis d‘un singulier ou d’un pluriel, selon [plusieurs règles](http://www.aidenet.eu/h_sans.htm) ou la préférence du locuteur.

Comment: « si *aucun* est au pluriel » : qu'est-ce que ça veut dire ? Exemple ?

Answer (score 6):

En règle générale, on utilise le nombre qui serait utilisé si la phrase n'était pas négative.

Par exemple,

> une dictée sans faute
>   une dictée sans fautes

Les deux sont corrects ici, mais utiliser l'un ou l'autre indique que l'on s'attend à trouver une ou plusieurs fautes en temps normal.

> Aucune faute ne peut être trouvée dans cette dictée
>   <strike>Aucune fautes ne peuvent être trouvées dans cette dictée</strike>

Ici, la seconde phrase est fausse. « Aucune » est toujours singulier et suivi d'un singulier.

> Il n'y a pas de fromage
>   Il n'y a pas de fromages

Un peu comme dans le premier cas, les deux sont corrects. La première phrase se réfère à *du fromage* de façon non quantifiée (il n'y a pas de fromage en général), alors que la seconde phrase se réfère à l'absence de différents types de fromage (camembert, brie, gruyère, tomme de chèvre, etc.)

> Pas un seul athlète n'a franchi cette barre
>   <strike>Pas un seul athlètes n'a franchi cette barre</strike>

Comme dans le second cas, la première phrase est correcte et la seconde est fausse.

Comment: Dans la dernière phrase, on pourrait cependant écrire « Pas un seul des athlètes n'a franchi cette barre ». Il est même envisageable, je pense, de mettre le verbe au pluriel pour insister sur le nombre à l'image de « Pas un seul des athlètes ; ils n'ont pas franchi cette barre »

Answer (score 4):

On met un pluriel après "sans" dans l'expression "X sans Y", si X est habituellement composé de plusieurs exemplaires de Y. Sinon on met le singulier.

Exemple : "une trousse sans stylos" est correct, "une voiture sans moteur" aussi, alors qu'"un ordinateur sans claviers" est faux.

Comment: Je vois pas ce qu'il y a d'inhabituel à avoir plusieurs claviers par ordinateur… :p

Comment: Moi non plus : je tape alternativement en anglais et en français et ai deux claviers, QWERTY et AZERTY.Probablement chacun des hémisphères cérébraux travaille à tour de rôle. :D

Answer (score 1):

Sans peut, selon le sens, être suivi du singulier ou du pluriel. On écrira toujours au singulier les noms dits abstraits : Être sans pitié. Cela se comprend sans peine. Un orateur est sans passion quand il n’est pas animé par la passion. Cet homme est sans passions s’il ignore les passions. On opposera un couteau sans manche, qui devrait en avoir un, mais un seul, à un gilet sans manches, qui en aurait deux, s’il en avait. Il est sorti sans chapeau ni chaussures. Dans de nombreux cas, cependant, la nuance de sens est si mince que l’on trouvera aussi bien le singulier que le pluriel : C’est un acteur sans défaut ou sans défauts (Littré). De même : Cet homme est mort sans enfant, sans héritier, ou sans enfants, sans héritiers. Pourtant, dès lors que ce dont on parle peut suggérer l’idée de pluralité, c’est le pluriel qui est le plus fréquent. On écrira : un devoir sans fautes, en jugeant qu’un tel devoir aurait d’ordinaire comporté plusieurs fautes (qu’une faute ne vient jamais seule), plutôt qu’un devoir sans faute, sauf si l’on veut insister sur le caractère exceptionnel de la chose, comme on dirait : sans aucune faute, sans la moindre faute.