# Dans quels cas doit-on utiliser le pluriel après « sans »?

Tags: grammaire, pluriel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quand faut-il mettre un pluriel après un mot indiquant l'absence d'un élément?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/170/quand-faut-il-mettre-un-pluriel-apres-un-mot-indiquant-labsence-dun-element)

J'ai noté qu'on utilise le nom pluriel après « sans » dans certains circonstances (*sans fautes*, *sans gants*, etc.) et le nom singulier dans autres (*sans faute*, *sans peur*).  Quelles sont les règles pour l'usage du pluriel et du singulier après « sans » ?