# Pluralization for a count of zero items

Tags: grammaire, pluriel, nombres

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quand faut-il mettre un pluriel après un mot indiquant l'absence d'un élément?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/170/quand-faut-il-mettre-un-pluriel-apres-un-mot-indiquant-labsence-dun-element)

I've always wondered, should one pluralize nouns when the count of the particular item is 0, but there is a clear possibility of having more? Here is an example:

> Il y a deux sites web.
>   Il y a un site web.
>   Il y a zéro sites web.

It seems to me that only when the count is 1 that the noun shouldn't be pluralized, but I might be wrong. I also recently read an article for programming a pluralization function (albeit for English) that talked about the same rule.

I am French Canadian if it makes any difference.

Comment: Somewhat related: [« Quand faut-il mettre un pluriel après un mot indiquant l'absence d'un élément ? »](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/170)

Comment: I, the question asker, would say it's a perfect duplicate. I searched in english, that's why I didn't find it. This is an interesting problem for this site I suppose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [plural forms definition from gnu](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/gettext/Plural-forms.html), the plural form for French language is for everything > 1 (0 and 1 are not pluralized).

Everything below 2 is not pluralized in French language, in case of non-integer counting, you will write `1,5 objet` not  `1,5 objets`.

> Two forms, singular used for zero and one Exceptional case in the
>   language family. The header entry would be:
>
> ```
> Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=n>1;
> ```
>
> Languages with this property include:
>
> - Romanic family: Brazilian Portuguese, French

In English, only 1 is not pluralized, 0 and n > 1 are pluralized.

> Two forms, singular used for one only This is the form used in most
>   existing programs since it is what English is using. A header entry
>   would look like this:
>
> ```
> Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=n != 1;
> ```
>
> Languages with this property include:
>
> - Germanic family: English, German, Dutch, Swedish, Danish, Norwegian, Faroese
> - Romanic family: Spanish, Portuguese, Italian, Bulgarian
> - Latin/Greek family: Greek
> - Finno-Ugric family: Finnish, Estonian
> - Semitic family: Hebrew
> - Artificial: Esperanto
> - Finno-Ugric family: Hungarian
> - Turkic/Altaic family: Turkish

Comment: Now, that's some one unusual reference :)

Comment: It's unusual but relates very directly to my problem. +1.

Comment: @F'x : right ;) But this is the one I used for many translation problems (in software development)

Comment: This is fine for integers, but for decimals 1.5 should be singular as well

Comment: @Shlublu : you're right, I edit my answer

Comment: On the other hand, the Mozilla docs claim that "some French speaking places treat 0 as plural": https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Localization_and_Plurals

Answer (score 5):

In French we use the singular for all quantity that is below 2.
**This means that even 1.5, for us, is singular**:

> Il y a deux sites web.
>   Il y a un site web.
>   Il y a zéro site web.
>   Il y a un site web et demi (si le second n'est pas fini :)).

Ou encore

> Il y a 2 sites web.
>   Il y a 1 site web.
>   Il y a 0 site web.
>   Il y a 1,5 site web.

More details [here](http://www.druide.com/points_de_langue_43.html) (first section of the document).

Comment: J'ai appris à lire _il y a 1,5 site web_ comme _il y a un site web et demi_, ce qui explique peut-être la règle.

Comment: Sans doute oui. Pareil en ce qui me concerne.

Comment: En passant un site web n'est pas fractionnable.

Comment: Ça, ça dépend du prestataire.

Comment: @Knu Il y a un vigule cinq million d'années, alors...