# 0, -1 et les nombres decimaux sont-ils singuliers ou pluriels ?

Tags: grammaire, nombres, accord

Dans l'ordre d'idée de la question *[Is -1 singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/is-1-singular-or-plural)* posée sur English Language & Usage, quelle règle a-t-on en Français pour ces nombres ?

> - Zéro X
> - Moins un X
> - Nombres décimaux, par exemple 1,24 X

Comment: Cf : http://french.stackexchange.com/q/1130/86

Comment: @CédricJulien Is this a dupe of a dupe?

Comment: @Alenanno Absolutely not. It supersedes it.

Comment: @Evpok Argh! Right... decimaux! :D Anyway, good, I thought it would be interesting to see the French situation. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Comme [précisé ici](http://www.druide.com/points_de_langue_43.html) :

> En français, seules les quantités égales ou supérieures à 2 prennent la marque du pluriel.

Ce qui sous entend que pour tout **nombre réel** (donc décimaux compris) N respectant 0 ≤ N < 2, on fera l'accord au singulier.

De même, cette règle s'applique pour les chiffres négatifs. Ce qui nous donne :

- **Singulier** -2 < N < 2
- **Pluriel** |N| ≥ 2 (N ≤ -2 ou N ≥ 2)

Comment: Et à propos des nombres decimaux comme -4,56 / 0,2 / 1,24 ?

Comment: @Alenanno : c'est pour ça que j'avais précisé *nombre (réel)*, mais ce n'était clairement pas assez explicite, j'ai corrigé/édité.

Answer (score 0):

Cette considération n'a pas de sens. Il est impossible de quantifier un objet avec un nombre négatif. Il n'est pas possible d'avoir « -2 pomme(s) » dans une main. Un clavier ne peut pas être assemblé avec -2 vis. Ce n'est pas constructif.

L'utilisation de nombres négatifs dans le langage se matérialisera pas l'utilisation de l'absence + valeur absolue.
Ainsi je peux dire « Il me manque 2 pommes » ou encore « Je lui dois 5 bananes ». Cela n'a pas de sens de dire « Il me doit -5 banane(s) ». Les nombres négatifs ne sont qu'une abstraction mathématique.

Lorsque l'on manipule de tels objets mathématiques (ou mesures), la règle énoncée par Cédric est bien :

> Singulier pour les nombres tels que *abs(x) < 2*
>
> Pluriel pour les nombres tels que *abs(x) >= 2*

Ainsi on note : -1,5 degré et -2,5 degrés, -4 votes. Mais la phrase « J'ai obtenu -4 votes » est sémantiquement incorrecte, même si l'usage se généralise. On privilégiera « J'ai obtenu 4 votes négatifs ».

Le cas zéro est expliqué dans une autre de mes questions :
[Quand faut-il mettre un pluriel après un mot indiquant l'absence d'un élément ? — When to use plural after words that hint at a missing entity?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/170/)

Comment: First you state it makes no sense, and then you talk about "-2,5 degrees" and "-4 votes"... that sounds like a contradiction. You can face situations where you talk about "-X of something", apparently.

Comment: These examples are usage of mathematical objects or measurements. But you can't use them to talk about real objects.

Comment: I'm aware it's not normally used for objects. I think that's something out of discussion and you can assume I know things like this. But let's say I still want to use it in some cases, like when reporting data... For example: due to a lack of founding, we can't buy anymore planes, and actually we have a decrease. So, in a table summarizing that data, I want to write "-45 airplanes". Not everyday usage, I'd choose other expressions, but legit.

Comment: Je cite en vrac : « Popularité: moins 6 points pour Sarkozy » ([Le Figaro](http://goo.gl/xkIh6)), « Le thermomètre a frôlé les moins 30 degrés » ([Le Monde](http://goo.gl/sqoxz)), « quand on a une pomme de terre négative on n'a pas zéro pomme de terre, on en a moins. Moins une pomme de terre. » ([dÉsencyclopédie](http://goo.gl/io4pO)). Formes attestées, donc ça a du sens.

Comment: Les points, degrés sont des mesures. Et permet moi de douter de la désencyclopédie quand même :P une pomme de terre négative? La règle de Cédric est très bien, j'apportais juste une précision sémantique.

Comment: dÉsencyclopédie ou pas, c'est un emploi, donc ça a du sens. Si Hugo, dans un élan de folie avait écrit un bouquin avec de patates négatives, il aurait bien fallu trouver une règle. En ce qui concerne les mesures je ne vois pas le rapport : il faut quand même décider si on met au pluriel ou pas.

Comment: Certes, mais il ne l'a pas fait. Le rapport avec les mesures, c'est qu'elle admettent des valeurs négatives. Les objets non. Enfin, je veux viens reconnaitre que c'est alambiqué comme distinction, mais je trouvais que c'était intéressant à mentionner.