# Comment accorder avec des nombres à virgule ?

Tags: nombres, accord

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [0, -1 et les nombres decimaux sont-ils singuliers ou pluriels ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/0-1-et-les-nombres-decimaux-sont-ils-singuliers-ou-pluriels)

Laquelle de ces deux phrases est correctement accordée ?

> J'ai besoin de 1,5 **kilogramme** de farine.

ou

> J'ai besoin de 1,5 **kilogrammes** de farine.

Quelle est la règle ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pour avoir regardé ça il y a un certain temps dans le Grevisse et autres ouvrages de référence, je me souviens que c'est au choix du lecteur.

> 1,5 cheval ou 1,5 chevaux

Si la chose en question est une quantité indénombrable, on préférera le pluriel au-dessus de 1.

> 1,5 mètres de corde

Mais l'internet ne me donne pas raison et a tendance à préférer la règle >= 2.
Une bonne raison pour cela est qu'on peut dire **un kilogramme et demi de farine**.

Sinon, dans le cas d'unités, le plus simple est d'**utiliser le symbole**, qui ne s'accorde jamais (et ne nécessite pas de traduction, sauf exceptions, suivez mon regard).

> J'ai besoin de 1,5 **kg** de farine.

(Question subsidiaire : Faut-il élider le *de* devant *1* ? 
« J'ai besoin **d'1**,5 kg de farine. »)

Answer (score 0):

D'après mon *Français au Bureau* (6e éd., p. 531), **le pluriel ne s'applique qu'aux nombres égaux ou supérieurs à deux**, peu importe leur forme, donc le singulier est requis ici.

Le cas ne semble pas être mentionné dans le *Ramat de la Typographie* (éd. 2005) ni dans *Le Bon Usage* (14e éd.), qui (pour autant que je puisse en juger) s'intéresse à la forme du pluriel plutôt qu'à la situation dans laquelle on l'emploie.

---

Quand à question soulevé par Impair, que je sache, on n'élide que devant une autre lettre, même si il y a élision à l'oral. Un chiffre n'est pas à proprement parler un mot, c'est l'adjectif numéral qui en est un.

Comment: La formulation de la règle me semble douteuse... *supérieur à deux* ? Donc *J'ai mangé deux fraise.* ? J'imagine que tu voulais dire * supérieur ou égal à deux*

Comment: [« Quand une relation d'ordre sur un ensemble E est notée ≥, l'expression x ≥ y se lit « x est supérieur à y ». »](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sup%C3%A9rieur)

Comment: Ça c'est ton côté maths qui ressort :-) Mais je crains que dans le français courant il ne faille préciser *ou égal*...