# La Pluralisation de mot "seconde"

Tags: grammaire, usage

Récemment, j'ai utilisé une appli qui permet la lecture de la musique, dont les paroles sont aussi affichées. Il y a surtout une fonctionnalité qui permet d'ajuster la vitesse des paroles, mais j'ai constaté ces irrégularités sur les messages affichés :

Quand j'appuie sur le bouton avancer, je vois :

```
0.5 seconde d'avance 
1.0 seconde d'avance
1.5 seconde d'avance
2.0 secondes d'avance
2.5 secondes d'avance
```

Cependant, si j'appuie le bouton reculer, je vois :

```
0.5 secondes de retard 
1.0 secondes de retard 
1.5 secondes de retard 
2.0 secondes de retard 
2.5 secondes de retard
```

On voit que dans le cas de "retard," seule la forme plurielle "***secondes***" est utilisée.

Je suis encore un élève quant à la langue française, donc je ne sais pas si c'est quelque chose que je ne comprends pas à la grammaire, ou si ce n'est simplement qu'une erreur.

Pourquoi ça ?

Comment: Probablement une erreur : bon nombre d'informaticiens ont des difficultés pour rédiger leur documentation technique comme ici, alors, l'orthographe dans ce genre de contexte …

Comment: @Personne S'il n'y avait que les informaticiens mon pôv' monsieur... ;-)

Comment: *Parole d'informaticien*
Une documentation technique? Qu'est-ce, un animal exotique ?

Comment: Je suis pointilleux mais on ne parle pas de documentation ici mais d'interface utilisateur. En général je lis peu la documentation mais l'interface est primordiale pour moi. Le problème est mineur ici, à la place du développeur j'aurais probablement utilisé "n seconde(s) de retard". @Thélée_Lavoie, québécois?

Comment: @vc74 … entre une IHM et une documentation, le problème du rédacteur est le même, surtout pour des lettres inaudibles pour lui et muettes pour les poètes :-)

Comment: @Personne J'ai régulièrement travaillé dans des endroits où le développeur ne s'occupait pas de la documentation utilisateur ou même technique, une autre équipe s'en chargeant. Par contre l'interface (et ses messages) est très souvent réalisée par un développeur.

Comment: Pas grave, ça donne de la job aux autres ! @vc74 [Définitivement](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=d%c3%a9finitivement&id=1102) !

Comment: @vc74 … *du* job, il est masculin dans l'hexagone. J'entends plus souvent  :  « Ça donne du *travail* aux autres », donner du travail à qqn est noble, et, « Ça fait un *job* pour les autres » c'est occuper quelqu’un ou lui faire faire une tâche non essentielle du point de vue du locuteur.

Comment: @Personne D'où ma question sur la nationalité de Thélée_Lavoie. Je crois que son 
 commentaire initial a été effacé d'ailleurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ce n'est qu'une erreur de l'application. L'usage et de ne mettre au pluriel qu'à partir de 2, indépendamment de toute autre considération.

Voir [0, -1 et les nombres decimaux sont-ils singuliers ou pluriels ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/0-1-et-les-nombres-decimaux-sont-ils-singuliers-ou-pluriels/1977)?

On peut aussi noter qu'il y a une autre erreur potentielle dans cette application. Sauf si la configuration de localisation définit un point décimal, comme par exemple l'anglais, le séparateur décimal devrait être une virgule, et l'appli devrait donc afficher :

> **0,5** seconde d'avance