# « Ne pas faire d’erreur » ou « ne pas faire d’erreurs » : singulier ou pluriel ?

Tags: pluriel, négation

A l'origine la consigne<sup>1</sup> est :

> Être attentif et ne pas faire d’erreurs.

Malgré l'attention que l'on porte à l'objet de notre occupation, on peut commettre une *ou* plusieurs erreurs.

- Doit-on laisser le singulier ?
- Peut-on accepter le pluriel ?
- Y a-t-il un ou plusieurs contextes pour préférer l'une à l'autre  expression ?

---

<sup>1 - Le titre du chapitre, l'exhortation ou tout autre indication, ordre, conseil ...</sup>

Comment: Les deux sont acceptables (https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/170), savoir laquelle est préférable c'est très subjectif. Et les contextes sont assez évidents à trouver… la question c'est « s'attend-on à une erreur ou à plusieurs » ? Bref, tout ceci a déjà été traité il me semble.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je n'avais pas réussi à trouver la solution sur le site, et les solutions proposées lorsque j'ai rédigé le titre ne correspondaient pas au sujet. Pour le pluriel j'hésite : il s'agit du titre d'un chapitre où l'on parle de plusieurs erreurs possibles, mais une seule possible à la fois selon des contexte chaque fois différents... ce qui devrait permettre de mettre l'un ou l'autre, ou de jouer la solution à pile ou face... pour le moment je laisse le pluriel, mais j'aimerais connaître le choix qu'adopteraient les lecteurs.

Comment: Tout dépend de ce que tu veux dire, dans quel contexte on peut trouver la consigne. 
Dans un QCM on pourrai le mettre au pluriel "ne pas faire `d'erreurs` dans les réponses", tandis qu'un chirgurien ne doit pas faire `d'erreur` (sous-entendu que l'erreur serait fatale). Encore une fois, comme dit plus haut ceci est très subjectif et les deux sont acceptables.