# « Lequel » ou « lesquels » dans « Ils n’ont aucun caractère comparable sur __ baser leur comparaison »

Tags: pluriel, accord, pronoms-relatifs

Instinctivement, je mettrais « lesquels » dans cette phrase parce que dans l'ensemble les comparaisons se basent souvent sur plusieurs « caractères comparables » (du moins dans cet exemple). Donc la phrase serait :

> Ils n’ont  aucun caractère comparable sur lesquels baser leur
>   comparaison.

Mais j'hésite parce qu'il me semble que le pronom doit s'accorder en nombre avec "caractère comparable" qui doit s'accorder avec "aucun". Donc la phrase serait :

> Ils n’ont  aucun caractère comparable sur lequel baser leur
>   comparaison.

Merci pour vos conseils !

Comment: Sujet lié: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/170/quand-faut-il-mettre-un-pluriel-apr%c3%a8s-un-mot-indiquant-labsence-dun-%c3%a9l%c3%a9ment. La réponse qui à été donné pour *aucun* n'est pour autant pas nécessairement applicable dans ce cas plus complexe.

Answer (score 6):

Le pronom ici s'accorde avec "caractère" donc vous devez utiliser lequel.
Mais votre phrase reste incorrecte, je pense que dire:
"Ils n'ont aucun caractère comparable." est suffisant pour comprendre le sens de la phrase.

Comment: Le fait qu'une phrase soit rendondante peut la rendre éventuellement maladroite, mais pas obligatoirement incorrecte.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, but aren’t “comparaisons” used to determine (& can’t they be based on) both similarities **and differences** between things being compared?  If so, wouldn’t the total lack of “caractères comparables” itself provide enough information on which a comparison could be based? (or at least wouldn’t a comparison first be required to determine that no comparable traits exist & not the other way around?) If so, maybe the problem, if any, with the example sentence is not one of redundancy (which I agree, @biozic , does not render it incorrect), but one of logic.

Comment: Your right Papa Poule. In the original text, this sentence is used to show a fallacy. Nonetheless, my gramatical question remains.

Comment: Indeed, out of context, the original sentence is just a statement, so there is no logic, so no fallacy in it. Anyway, an error in the logic it describes doesn't make a sentence incorrect, does it?

Answer (score 1):

Tout dépend du sens visé. Si il s'agit de dire qu'il n'existe pas un caractère comparable qui puisse servir de base alors la deuxième formule correspond à ce cas :

> Ils n’ont aucun caractère comparable sur lequel baser leur comparaison.

Mais plus probablement, l'intention est de dire qu'il n'y a pas de caractères comparables qui puissent servir de base, auquel cas, le pluriel correspondrait mieux au sens :

> Ils n'ont aucuns caractères comparables sur lesquels baser leur comparaison.

Pour mettre le nombre en évidence, on peut comparer les formulations suivantes :

> Jean n'a aucun caractère comparable qui pourra lui servir de base.
>
> Jean n'a aucuns caractères comparables qui pourront lui servir de base

Comment: Bien que grammaticalement juste, la version plurielle me choque. En règle générale, je suis d'accord avec ce qui a été dit [dans la réponse acceptée](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/813/7224) à la question citée ailleurs par Stéphane, et je trouve qu'elle s'applique à ce cas : parmi un ensemble de caractères, pas un seul ne peut servir de comparaison. En-dessous d'un, on utilise le singulier en français.

Comment: Du coup j'hésiste. Une réponse en faveur de "Ça dépend", une autre (et un commentaire) en faveur du singulier. Le deuxième exemple de Gam Pub est celui qui correspondrait le plus mais est-il bon ?